# Is there a standard POSIX way of doing `tac`

Tags: solaris, aix, posix, hp-ux

Looks like at least IBM AIX and HP-UX don't have the `tac` command by default.

Is there a way to do this using just basic posix standard shell utilities available on all UNIX systems?

Furthermore, is `SMCcoreu` package on Solaris (which provides `tac` on SunOS, installed by default?

Comment: Would this work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/744093/1472474 ?

Comment: Using `sed`: `sed '1!G;h;$!d' file.txt`